# Stacking percentage reduction depending on input (java script)

Tags: javascript, math

I'm sure this is simple enough for someone better at maths than me, but the solution is eluding me.

I need to take a number, the block chain height, which at every 500 thousand blocks, reduces the reward by 5%.

The original reward is 3 per block. So block 500001 would be 2.85, block 1,000,001 would be 2.7075, block 1,500,001 would be 2.572125, etc.

This happens all the way to block 30,000,000 so using case or if is not practical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't quite tell if you need continuous reduction, or "sudden" reduction after crossing the next 500,000 (for example, is the reward at block 499,999 still 3%?).

Assuming you need "sudden" reduction, you first calculate the number of reductions.

```
var blocks = 10000000; // 10 million, just as an example
var reductions = Math.floor(blocks / 500000);
```

Then apply the reductions to your reward

```
var reward = 0.03 * Math.pow(0.95, reductions);
```

That will take off 5% (by multiplying by 0.95) the correct number of times. The result will be a decimal percent (like 0.0285 representing 2.85%, etc).

If you need a continuous reduction, you can actually just remove the `Math.floor` from the calculation of reductions above.

Comment: Hi, no not a continuous reduction but would this remove 0.15 each time or would it remove 5% of the current block reward? So if it was previously reduced by 0.15, the next reduction would be 5% of 2.85

Comment: @NotoriousPyro that's right. A continuous reduction would agree with a "sudden" reduction at the 500,000 breakpoints, but would slide smoothly to those reward values instead of changing suddenly. Both methods reduce "cumulatively", as in 5% of the previous value, not 5% of the original, giving 3, 2.85, 2.7075, etc as you required.

Comment: One thing I don't understand about your answer is 0.03. Where did you get this number from when multiplying by math.pow?

Comment: Actually, that works perfectly with 0.03 adjusted to 3.

Comment: If you start with 3, then you'll get answers like `2.85` indicating 2.85%. If you start with 0.03 then you'll get answers like `0.0285` indicating 2.85%. Using either one is fine of course - some might prefer the decimal if doing further calculations with the percent, but it's really no huge deal either way.